# React and Redux - ComponentDidUpdate Async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning React and Redux, I'm doing a basic ToDo list.

I'm having an issue with the `componentDidUpdate`.

I delete a row over a `dispatch` to a redux action, and then in the componentDidUpdate I wait for the change in the props like:

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
  if (this.props.todoDelted) {
    this.refreshTodoList()
  } 
}
```

The problem is, that there's another `props` that are being updated too, and `todoDelted` is the first to update. When I compare with `prevProps` todoDeleted is always `undefined`, since it updated just once.

How can I run `this.refreshTodoList()` just once and not every time a prop is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not necessary to use `componentDidUpdate` method.

The `dispatch` method returns Promise, so you can write something like this:

`this.props.dispatch(someAction(payload)).then(this.refreshTodoList);`

Your function will be called just once.

Comment: I get: `_this.props.dispatch(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Alright. If you are using reducers, you can make `todoDeleted` by default is `false`. Just change it to `true` in the reducer.

Comment: that's what I'm doing now, I think maybe I am some how, rendering the component three times, because the only change in the state is the `todoDelted` from false to true 3 times

Comment: Do you store `todoDelted` in reducer? To be more concrete I want to see your redux state. Also try to use `componentWillReceiveProps` event

Comment: `dispatch` does not return a promise unless you have some middleware to do it like `redux-thunk`

Comment: Well my issue was it was updating the state for all todo items, that why it was running several times. Sorry.